# Pybrain TypeError while binarizing the target

Tags: python

I hava a following error using pybrain _convertToOneOfMany( )

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-f1c0d3ad67e6> in <module>()
 19 print y_train
 20 ds_train.setField('target', y_train[:, np.newaxis])
 ---> 21 ds_train._convertToOneOfMany( )
 22 

\pybrain\datasets\classification.pyc in _convertToOneOfMany(self, bounds)
140         newtarg = zeros([len(self), self.nClasses], dtype='Int32') + bounds[0]
141         for i in range(len(self)):
--> 142             newtarg[i, int(oldtarg[i])] = bounds[1]
143         self.setField('target', newtarg)
144         self.setField('class', oldtarg)

TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to int
```

I have 70 classes (country names) and the list of the targets y_train looks like this:

```
[u'\u0418\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438\u044f'
u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'
u'\u041c\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043a\u043a\u043e' ...,
u'\u041d\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0434\u044b'
u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u0446\u0438\u044f'
u'\u0412\u044c\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0430\u043c']
```

What could be the matter? Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the same: pybrain demands targets of only integer type so you have to index whatever there is.

Answer (score 0):

`newtarg = zeros([len(self), self.nClasses], dtype='Int32') + bounds[0]`

The 'Int32' cannot be understood. So, I changed it in the classification.py (in the Pybrain installed directory in your Mac) to:

```py
import numpy as np

newtarg = zeros([len(self), self.nClasses], dtype=np.int32) + bounds[0]
```

Then it works.